# how to delay drawing

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show the proccess of filling an area line by line. The problem is: even if I create `QPixmap` from `QImage` every time I draw a new line (and also delay) and add it to `QGraphicsScene` in a loop, it doesn't update until the whole thread is finished.

Answer (score 0):

`QTest::qWait` does the trick. And using `QGraphicsPixmapItem` for an actual display of the proccess instead of `QPixmap` itself. I use `QPainter` initialized from `QPixmap` and then just reset the pixmap for the pixmap item.

```
QImage img = QImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, QImage::Format_RGB32);
img.fill(Qt::white);
QPixmap *pixmapFill = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
QGraphicsPixmapItem pixmapItem(*pixmapFill);
fillScene->addItem(&pixmapItem);
pixmapItem.setPixmap(*pixmapFill);
// ...
for (auto point : *points) {
    QTest::qWait(delay);
    painter.drawLine(point.x(), point.y(), xBarrier, point.y());
    pixmapItem.setPixmap(*pixmapFill);
}
```